# Eigenvalue reachability for matrix problems

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Suppose I am considering the following matrix-valued equation:

\begin{align}
A = B + C,\\
\text{where } A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
\end{align}

**My aim is:**

Given $B$, I want to  find a particular $C$ such that I can ensure that $A$ obtains a particular set of eigenvalues.

Initially $A$ and $B$ do not share any common eigenvalues.

**My question is:**

Is it possible to "reach" every single set of eigenvalues for $A$, from $B$, using $C$? If $A$ is to remain symmetric, positive-definite is it possible to find some minimal restrictions on this additive $C$ matrix such that this is possible (e.g. $C$ only needs to be diagonal? Or $C$ only needs to be rank 1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though the recipe I have in mind may not be very satisfactory. Assuming $B$ is diagonalizable, diagonalize it as $PDP^{-1}$, then take $C=PEP^{-1}$ where $E$ is diagonal with $E_{ii}=\lambda_i-D_{ii}$, and $\lambda_i$ is the desired $i$th eigenvalue. If $B$ is not diagonalizable, first perturb it so that it becomes diagonalizable (rolling the perturbation into the final $C$) and then apply the same recipe.

In terms of possible assumptions on what classes of $C$'s you can use, that's a bit of an ambitious question; it would be easier to answer with particular assumptions rather than asking such a broad question.

Comment: If I say, bot $A$ and $B$ should be symmetric, positive-definite do you think that not enough of an assumption to try and constrain $C$ to a particular class of matrices?

Comment: @pche8701 But what assumption on $C$ do you actually want to impose, besides that one requirement on the $A$ that you end up with?

Comment: I was wondering about the following constraints for example: (1) Is it possible for $C$ to be purely diagonal to ensure that all eigenvalues are reachable. Or, (2) If $C$ is rank 1, is it possible to reach all eigenvalues.